# Azure AD B2C Rest API Call

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We need help with Azure AD B2C. We are trying to use both Basic AuthN and ClientCertificate AuthN to make a POST API call but there is no mention of it in the Microsoft docs. Is it possible to use both AuthenticationType together in one technical profile for making an API call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Additional Custom Headers in REST API call in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427429/passing-additional-custom-headers-in-rest-api-call-in-azure-ad-b2c)

Comment: No - type is in "AuthenticationType" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT you have given link to my another question only. Is there any way we can have both the Basic and ClientCertificate AuthN type in one Technical Profile. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use more than one authentication type.